# Django GUnicorn in production is calling setup.php

Tags: php, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I was checking my logs with supervisor and I got this

```
Not Found: /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php
```

does someone know why this is trying to reach a php file?

I'm running django 11.06 with gninx and gunicorn.

Comment: That may just mean that some automated script tried to check if your server has phpmyadmin and if so, is the setup open.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as a request from a random client or an automated bot for finding any vulnerability or something; logs showing 404 is not bad as long as your URL config does not match the request anyway